# Send POST request from vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net, http-post

I'm developing an application for Cisco IP phone to send messages. Currently I have the HTML code to send the request. But I need to send request from VB.NET therefore I can integrate with one of my application. please find the below mentioned HTML Code,

```html
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
    <form method="POST" name="XML" action="http://Reed:password@192.168.13.112/CGI/Execute">
    <textarea name="XML">
    <CiscoIPPhoneText><Text>Hi Mr.Anton..! Welcome ..!</Text>                       </CiscoIPPhoneText>
    </textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="POST"/>
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Currently this code is working with HTML. I need to send these information to the IP Phone using VB.NET

Your help is highly appreciated.